# On connecting usb to ethernet adapter, Xubuntu shows no internet, but Windows 7 works fine

Tags: networking, usb, xubuntu, ethernet

Sorry, I have to start this post again, since the previous post couldnot solve the problem. I have a dual-booted system - Windows 7 and Xubuntu. Previously, I had an internet connection in both Win 7 and Xubuntu through an ethernet cable connected to the rear side of CPU (in the internet port). 
 Recently, the internet port got damaged and I bought a USB to ethernet adapter. On plugging in the adapter (with the ethernet cable) to a USB port, the internet has returned and works fine in Windows 7. However, on restarting the system and opening Xubuntu, it shows me disconnected : You are offline. I configured the VPN and created an ethernet connection with all the functioning IP Settings that were there in Windows. Still, it was of no avail. 
 After fruitless efforts of all day and night for a few days, I have decided to ask for advice from the experts in Ubuntu Community. I am a complete noob in Linux, so please offer easy-to-understand help.
 Through long hours of googling, visiting forums and scrambling through various sites, I have discovered that these information through linux commands might help. I am listing them below.

1. Output in terminal of

> sudo ifconfig

Code:

```
[sudo] password for subhankar:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:40:f2:d1:8b:86  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe400000-fe420000

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:01:00:9c:34
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11743 (11.7 KB)  TX bytes:11743 (11.7 KB)
```

2. Output of

> lsusb

Code:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0fe6:9700 Kontron (Industrial Computer Source / ICS Advent) DM9601 Fast Ethernet Adapter

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

3. Output of

> sudo lshw -C network -numeric

Code:

```
*-network 

       description: Ethernet interface

       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503]

       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]

       physical id: 19

       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0

       logical name: eth0

       version: 04

       serial: e8:40:f2:d1:8b:86

       capacity: 1Gbit/s

       width: 32 bits

       clock: 33MHz

      capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 

10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e 

driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 

port=twisted pair

       resources: irq:26 memory:fe400000-fe41ffff memory:fe428000-

fe428fff ioport:f080(size=32)

  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface

       physical id: 1

       logical name: eth2

       serial: 00:e0:01:00:9c:34

       size: 100Mbit/s

       capacity: 100Mbit/s

       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 

autonegotiation

       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=dm9601 

driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=half firmware=Davicom DM96xx 

USB 10/100 Ether link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

4. Output of

> nm-tool

Code:

```
NetworkManager Tool
State: disconnected


- Device: eth2 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:  

            Wired
  Driver:            dm9601
  State:             unavailable


Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:E0:01:00:9C:34

  Capabilities:


   Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties    

Carrier:         off

- Device: eth0 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:  
            Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable


Default:           no
  HW Address:        E8:40:F2:D1:8B:86

  Capabilities:


  Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

A point to mention here : eth2 is my existing ethernet connection which I get when I plug in the usb adapter to a usb port in CPU. When I unplug the usb adapter from cpu, I donot get the eth2 connection in 'ifconfig' statement. That's why I believe that is my valid ethernet connection.

5. Output of

> cat /etc/network/interfaces

Code:

```
# 

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

(N.B. I edited the Interfaces files and included the last 2 lines of code 'auto eth2... inet dhcp', seeing if that would help. But, my effort was useless. Still no internet in Xubuntu. Oh God, I am going almost crazy.)

6. Output of

> cat /etc/resolve.conf

Code:

```
nameserver 172.16.0.1
nameserver 10.10.0.1
```

7. Output of

> cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Code:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=E8:40:F2:D1:8B:86,00:E0:01:00:9C:34,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

8. Output of

> cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

Code:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

9. Output of

> lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

Code:

```
00:19.0 

Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network 

Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 

Device [8086:2017]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

(Now I am listing the kernel version of my Xubuntu, because I read that this matters while installing drivers in Xubuntu).

10. Output of

> uname -a

Code:

```
Linux subhankar-desktop 3.19.0-28-generic #30~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 1 09:33:32 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

11. Output of

> ifconfig -a

(N. B. The connection is established for a few seconds in Xubuntu and then it again becomes disconnected. This can be confirmed from eth2 TX bytes that is shown below. The connection is for so short time and so feeble that I cannot open any website with it.)

Code:

```
eth0      Link 

          encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:40:f2:d1:8b:86 UP BROADCAST 
          MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe400000-fe420000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:01:00:9c:34  
          inet addr:172.22.40.145  Bcast:172.22.40.255 Mask:255.255.255.128 
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:1ff:fe00:9c34/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST    
          MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:7904 (7.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0     
          TX packets:579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:44563 (44.5 KB)  TX bytes:44563 (44.5 KB)
```

That's all the information I have at present. I know it has become too long, sorry for that, but I have furnished all the necessary information that I have at present. Please, please, please, ... anybody out there who can help me with my problem. I am very frustrated and deeply depressed. Any suggestion is welcome. Any fruitful help will be greatly appreciated. You are the only ones whom I can rely on right now. Thanks.

Comment: You have an IP address so you device can work. Maybe its just the DNS settings or something like that (I'm not an expert). I would try to create a live USB image of Ubuntu 14.04 and see if it works with the default settings. Keep possitive, after all you are learning a lot with this :)

Comment: Thanks katu, but I can't find peace unless I solve this problem. All my work is hanged up. I am day and night struggling with this. I am not a Ubuntu guy. That's why I can't even locate the problem. I believe some expert here can help. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You can also check if the DNS, IP range, Broadcast IP and Mask match the ones you get in Windows. They look odd to me. Normally the mask ends in 0 and the DNS is in the same range. You can also try to set these values manually to the values that work in Windows.

Comment: Yes, Katu, they match exactly as that in Windows and also the values have been entered manually in IPv4 settings while creating the ethernet connection in Xubuntu. Thanks for the quick reply. What worries me is that why the connection is not constant, but intermittent (as you can check from my two codes with same ifconfig command at the beginning and at the end). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual machine, make sure your Ethernet device is connected. For VMWare, under removable devices, check to see if 'Network Adapter' is connected. This was my issue, and I had a similar series of messages as you posted above, except that in dmesg, I had the error 'link is down', which is the same kind of error that you would get if the ethernet is physically disconnected. Stupid mistake, but worth checking.